# Java ServiceLoader can't find class

Tags: java, jogl, java-3d

In the Jogamp Java3D Font3D class there is this piece of code

```
final ServiceLoader<GeometryService> gsLoader =
    ServiceLoader.load(GeometryService.class);

final Iterator<GeometryService> iter = gsLoader.iterator();
if (iter.hasNext()) return iter.next();

throw new IllegalStateException("No GeometryService implementation");
```

It works fine in Eclipse but when I package my work into a jar file it fails. I have no experience with this area of Java alas, I'd never even heard of ServiceLoader until a few days ago. How can I debug what's going on here. How can I tell where ServiceLoader is looking and why it can't find the class?

Comment: Does your JAR contain a `META-INF/services/this.is.the.package.GeometryService` file? Or if this is a modular JAR, does it declare the service in `module-info.java`? (NOTE: the previous suggestions assume you want to load your own implementation of a service.) If you're trying to load service implementations from other JARs, are those JARs actually on your classpath when you run your application? In any case, please provide a [mre].

Comment: In my META-INF/services I've made a file called org.jogamp.java3d.GeometryService. The contents are "org.jogamp.java3d.utils". I can tell it's being looked at and now get the error  java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jogamp.java3d.GeometryService: Provider org.jogamp.java3d.utils

What should the file contain? The class lives in the same Jar as my code with the relative path org\jogamp\java3d\utils

Comment: `org.jogamp.java3d.utils` doesn't sound like a proper class name but as a package name.

Comment: I suspect you're right. Trying to work out the syntax.....

Comment: Fixed by setting contents of file to org.jogamp.java3d.utils.geometry.GeometryServiceImpl Thanks VERY much for your help :-)

Comment: Question already answered here: https://forum.jogamp.org/No-GeometryService-implementation-found-Font3D-related-td4043127.html